# Getting errors on predicted probabilities from sklearn Random Forest classifier

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

Citing sklearn:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as the
>   mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest.

My question: is there a way to extract the mean square error for each predicted probability?

One should have the predicted probabilities from each tree for example, but I can't find how.

**EDIT:**

This is sklearn code for `predict_proba` function:

```
def predict_proba(self, X):
    """Predict class probabilities for X.
    The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as
    the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
    class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same
    class in a leaf.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        The input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted to
        ``dtype=np.float32``. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be
        converted into a sparse ``csr_matrix``.
    Returns
    -------
    p : array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes], or a list of n_outputs
        such arrays if n_outputs > 1.
        The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the
        classes corresponds to that in the attribute `classes_`.
    """
    # Check data
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)

    # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
    n_jobs, _, _ = _partition_estimators(self.n_estimators, self.n_jobs)

    # Parallel loop
    all_proba = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                         backend="threading")(
        delayed(parallel_helper)(e, 'predict_proba', X,
                                  check_input=False)
        for e in self.estimators_)

    # Reduce
    proba = all_proba[0]

    if self.n_outputs_ == 1:
        for j in range(1, len(all_proba)):
            proba += all_proba[j]

        proba /= len(self.estimators_)

    else:
        for j in range(1, len(all_proba)):
            for k in range(self.n_outputs_):
                proba[k] += all_proba[j][k]

        for k in range(self.n_outputs_):
            proba[k] /= self.n_estimators

    return proba
```

So it seems I can access single tree probability easily with the `all_proba` array.

Going to implement this!

Comment: how to you define MSE for a classification problem?

Comment: Each tree in the forest compute a probability, then you have the mean as output; simply compute deviations from that mean.